# mysql alter table relationship cascade

Tags: mysql

I have this piece of code to alter a tables relationship but I want to add cascade update and delete operations do I need to add cascade update cascade delete to this code

```
ALTER TABLE product_images
ADD FOREIGNKEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(product_id)
```

this is a one to many relationship I hope my code is right for a start. I have a products table and a product_images table which has many images for each product

Updated

```
ALTER TABLE product_images
ADD FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(product_id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those referential actions need to be specified. [`RESTRICT` is default](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/134872).

Comment: I tried that piece of code and it says the syntax is wrong do you know another version of the code for it to create a relationship in mysql

Comment: @KDM the syntax is wrong because `FOREIGNKEY` needs to be `FOREIGN KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it worked properly:

```
ALTER TABLE tb1
ADD CONSTRAINT relationship_name FOREIGN KEY fieldName REFERENCES tb2(fieldName);
```